# Project Euler 55 - Answer Only Off By 3 (strange!)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was solving this problem (found at http://projecteuler.net/problem=55) and I could not get it right so I searched for the answer.
It seems the answer my code is giving is only off by 3 **(mine: 246 , right: 249)**.
It would be nice for someone to to spot the mistake. I have been trying for 3 hours now...

Here is my code:

```
from time import time

def rev(x):
    return int(str(x)[::-1])

def Palindrome(x):
    if x == rev(x): return True
    else : return False

def test(x):
    steps = 0

    while True :
        if not Palindrome(x):
            steps += 1
        else:
            return False
        if steps > 50 :
            return True
        x += rev(x)


def main():
    starttime = time()
    lychrel = 0
    for i in range(1,10000):
        if test(i) : lychrel += 1
    elapsed = time() - starttime 
    print "The answer is %d found in %f seconds"  %(lychrel,elapsed) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, Stack Overflow isn't really a debugging service. You didn't include a description of what the problem should do, you didn't give us any indication you tried to solve this yourself or where you feel you misunderstood the problem or why your code doesn't produce the correct result.

Comment: I can understand your point but it is the only place that can do it. There are people that can help me and get reputation. I forgot to paste the PE problem and I have a difficulty editing it so here it is: (http://projecteuler.net/problem=55)

The rev and Palindrome functions work. I can not understand why anything else could make it throw the wrong result.

Comment: Then *add that to your question*; what I object to is you posting just the code, and a *doesn't work, why* line in a post, without any effort on your part to explain what part you need help with, and what you did so far yourself. If you have trouble editing, give us your best attempt and we can help clean that up.

Comment: I did not know what really did not work. So I wanted someone to 'unjam' me. I wrote the code and it did not work that's all.

Comment: I'll direct you to [Eric Lippert's blog post on debugging](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) then.

Answer (score 5):

From the description at http://projecteuler.net/problem=55

> Surprisingly, there are palindromic numbers that are themselves Lychrel numbers; the first example is 4994.

Your code does not recognize 4994 as a Lychrel number.

Comment: Did fixing that cause your code to produce the correct answer?

Comment: Yes. I just moved the x += rev(x) line just below the while loop. And... It's done!